# How to create eslint rule that denies usage of html tag or vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, eslint

Real example:

We are using Vuetify on our project.
We have custom component `<q-dialog>`, it's a wrapper around Vuetify's component `<v-dialog>`.

I want to deny using `<v-dialog>`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You're most likely going to have to create a [plugin](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins) and/or use your IDE to manage this - I don't think eslint can do this out of the box.